# continuous aggregate is too slower than hypertable

Tags: timescaledb

timescale-db continuous aggregate materialized only = true is about 100 times faster than materialized only = false.

i expect to continuous aggregate be faster than calculate from real time. but real time calculate is faster than continuous aggregate.

also in this link i shared more detail[timescaldb-forum](https://www.timescale.com/forum/t/timescaledb-continuous-aggregate-materialized-only-true-is-about-100-times-faster-than-materialized-only-false/1773)

i think continuous aggregate must be faster but they are too slow. i think something is wrong there

i turn materialized_view_only to true it works well then. problem is when is set materialized_view_only=false

Answer (score 0):

> i turn materialized_view_only to true it works well then. problem is when is set materialized_view_only=false

Thanks for sharing the solution!